# NTFS-3G: Using user mapping, all files become executable after boot to Windows

Tags: windows-7, fedora, ntfs, file-permissions, ntfs-3g

I have an NTFS partition shared between Windows 7 and Fedora 15. I added a [`.NTFS-3G/UserMapping`](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/user-mapping/) file to map my main user/group in Windows to my main user/group in Linux. This was fine until I booted to Windows and back to Linux, and then all files and most directories (except for .NTFS-3G and $RECYCLE.BIN) had the mode 0755.

I think I did something wrong. Has anyone had a similar problem? How do I get permissions on Linux to stay consistent between reboots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal. When you added the `UserMapping` file, it didn't became active immediately – you were still seeing all permissions as set by the `fmask`/`dmask` mount options.

When you rebooted (or more accurately, when the filesystem was mounted again), the ntfs-3g driver found your `UserMapping` file and switched to "NTFS permissions" mode, in which the permissions shown in `ls` and used by Linux are in fact the same as those used by Windows. It is impossible to translate some NTFS ACL combinations to POSIX ACLs, but the basic "read/write/execute" bits exist in both.

In other words, you are seeing all files being executable because **they *are* executable in Windows too**. This has always been the default, since Windows primarily uses the filename extension for executable files.

Comment: So at this point, I should just fix the permissions to how I want them, and they'll stay?

Comment: You could do that. But it's better if you do that in Windows, since it allows configuring inheritable ACLs - you can make it automatically add +x to directories only. Remember, however, that Windows respects the +x/Execute permission as well - you cannot run an .exe that lacks +x.